# Run batch files as administrator user

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, windows-pe

I have a segment with 100 computers.

I am booting each machne from WinPE OS located on a CD. After the OS has finished loading, I want to automatically run a batch file that will copy the CD to the C:\ drive.

My questions:

1. How can I edit the WinPe ISO to run the batch file automatically after booting?
2. Copy to C:\ drive required an admin privilages, how can I write it to run as admin? (I can't use "Run As" command since I dont know what the name and the password of admin on each computer are).

Comment: Unrelated to question, is there any reason you are booting each machine from a CD rather than a PXE-boot enviroment like Windows Deployment Services? That would be a bit easier than using a CD.

Comment: Yes, I dont have a PXE server, and I must use CD for another reasons.

Comment: Okay. In regards to copying the files to the hard disk, is there already an OS on there? or is this setting up an enviroment with nothing on the disk yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you've created the WinPE ISO, I presume it's with the WAIK?

When you're building the image, create a new text file in notepad called Winpeshl.ini and store it in the build_directory\mount\Windows\System32. In that file, call the batch file.

To make it a bit easier and quicker, see if [this link will help](http://www.iammacgyver.com/2011/02/easy-rdp-60-from-winpe-30-simple-boot.html). I used it to see when I was trying to auto-launch RDP from a WinPE enviroment as [asked in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/315855/am-i-allowed-to-add-rdc-to-a-winpe-boot-image)